# Struts 2 in eclipse giving "requested resource not found"

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, struts2, struts-config

CONSOLE OUTPUT

```
16 May, 2013 6:06:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin;.;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\adarsh\mysql\bin;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_04\bin;.;C:\apache-ant-1.8.4\bin;.;C:\apache-ant-1.8.4\lib;.;C:\Program Files (x86)\clisp-2.49
16 May, 2013 6:06:52 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Struts2Starter' did not find a matching property.
16 May, 2013 6:06:52 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
16 May, 2013 6:06:52 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
16 May, 2013 6:06:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 781 ms
16 May, 2013 6:06:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
16 May, 2013 6:06:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.34
```

CODE ERROR STARTS AFTER THIS

```
16 May, 2013 6:06:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: /struts-tags is already defined
16 May, 2013 6:06:53 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger info
INFO: Parsing configuration file [struts-default.xml]
16 May, 2013 6:06:54 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger error
SEVERE: Dispatcher initialization failed
Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/C:/adarsh/Struts/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Struts2Starter/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.3.4.1.jar!/struts-default.xml:29:72
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:69)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:390)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:436)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:69)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:278)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:383)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5306)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: Unable to load bean: type: class:com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory - bean - jar:file:/C:/adarsh/Struts/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Struts2Starter/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.3.4.1.jar!/struts-default.xml:29:72
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:235)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.register(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:102)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:180)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:66)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: Bean type class com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory with the name xwork has already been loaded by bean - jar:file:/C:/adarsh/Struts/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Struts2Starter/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.3.1.2.jar!/struts-default.xml:29:72 - bean - jar:file:/C:/adarsh/Struts/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Struts2Starter/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.3.4.1.jar!/struts-default.xml:29:72
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:219)
    ... 21 more
16 May, 2013 6:06:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/C:/adarsh/Struts/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Struts2Starter/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.3.4.1.jar!/struts-default.xml:29:72
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:449)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:69)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:278)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:383)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5306)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/C:/adarsh/Struts/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Struts2Starter/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.3.4.1.jar!/struts-default.xml:29:72
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:69)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:390)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:436)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: Unable to load bean: type: class:com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory - bean - jar:file:/C:/adarsh/Struts/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Struts2Starter/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.3.4.1.jar!/struts-default.xml:29:72
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:235)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.register(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:102)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:180)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:66)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: Bean type class com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory with the name xwork has already been loaded by bean - jar:file:/C:/adarsh/Struts/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Struts2Starter/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.3.1.2.jar!/struts-default.xml:29:72 - bean - jar:file:/C:/adarsh/Struts/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Struts2Starter/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.3.4.1.jar!/struts-default.xml:29:72
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:219)
    ... 21 more
16 May, 2013 6:06:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error filterStart
16 May, 2013 6:06:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/Struts2Starter] startup failed due to previous errors
16 May, 2013 6:06:54 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
16 May, 2013 6:06:54 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
16 May, 2013 6:06:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1926 ms
## Heading ##
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Caused by: **Unable to load bean**: type: class:com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory - bean - jar:file:/C:/adarsh/Struts/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Struts2Starter/WEB-INF/lib/**struts2-core-2.3.4.1.jar**!/struts-default.xml:29:72
>
> **Caused by: Bean type class com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory with the name xwork has already been loaded by bean** - jar:file:/C:/adarsh/Struts/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Struts2Starter/WEB-INF/lib/**struts2-core-2.3.1.2.jar**!/struts-default.xml:29:72 - bean - jar:file:/C:/adarsh/Struts/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Struts2Starter/WEB-INF/lib/**struts2-core-2.3.4.1.jar**!/struts-default.xml:29:72

You simply have multiple version of the Struts2 library in your project.

Remove all the further versions except the one you want to use, and you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible your WEB-INF\classes folder contains a struts.xml and eclipse is loading its struts.xml twice, after your clasess\struts.xml is loaded. 
Try cleaning your classes folder, or at least remove the struts.xml file that is there.